# How to see what version of JDK you are using

Tags: android-studio

How do i see what JDK version i am using in android studio? It says to do ctrl-shift-alt-s but all im seeing is sdk

Comment: take a look at this article https://phoenixnap.com/kb/check-java-version-on-mac-windows

Answer (score 1):

**Go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle**

[image]